# Data-binding to a select

Tags: jquery, select, jquery-mobile, knockout.js

I have a jquery function gets a all teams from a service.  How would i data-bind this to a select box?

```
function GetAvailableTeams() {
        $.support.cors = true; 
        var jqxhr =
        $.getJSON('http://localhost/Service.svc/GetTeamsAll',
          function (data) {
                teamViewModel.clearTeams();
                $.each(data.GetTeamsAllResult, 
                    function (key, val) {
                        teamViewModel.addTeam(val.TeamId, val.TeamName, true);
                    }
              ko.applyBindings(teamViewModel, document.getElementById("teamNameLabel"));
          })
         .success(function () {  })
         .error(function () { alert("Encountered error with the service: GetTeams. "); })
         .complete(function () { });
    }
```

Comment: I'm almost certain the Knockout JS homepage uses binding a select as their example.  Can't verify though, their site is loading for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to set up the correct properties of the select element and the
api will do it for you.

```
<select data-bind="options: ReferenceTypes, optionsText: 'TeamName', 
optionsCaption: 'Select...', optionsValue: 'Id', **value:TeamModel**">
</select>
```

Ex:
[knockoutjs mapping select data-bind options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9746042/knockoutjs-mapping-select-data-bind-options)

http://jsfiddle.net/madcapnmckay/Ba5gx/